# Why is Bubble Sort implementation looping forever?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

In class we are doing sorting algorithms and, although I understand them fine when talking about them and writing pseudocode, I am having problems writing actual code for them.

This is my attempt in Python:

```
mylist = [12, 5, 13, 8, 9, 65]

def bubble(badList):
    length = len(badList) - 1
    unsorted = True

    while unsorted:
        for element in range(0,length):
            unsorted = False
            if badList[element] > badList[element + 1]:
                hold = badList[element + 1]
                badList[element + 1] = badList[element]
                badList[element] = hold
                print badList
            else:
                unsorted = True

print bubble(mylist)
```

Now, this (as far as I can tell) sorts correctly, but once it finishes it just loops indefinitely.

How can this code be fixed so the function finishes properly and correctly sorts a list of any (reasonable) size?

P.S. I know I should not really have prints in a function and I should have a return, but I just have not done that yet as my code does not really work yet.

Comment: I thought it was an acknowledgement of error. Not a question.

Comment: god, this pisses me off. Why do they even teach a worthless algorithm like this in the first place. No knock at the question, just the source of it.

Comment: The post is essentially: "I have trouble coding, this is what I did, it doesn't work."  There's obviously an implicit "Can someone give me some pointers please?"  Unlike many homework questions, this one (a) is well written, (b) is upfront about being homework, and (c) includes a good attempt at solving the problem.  I don't think the lack of an actual question mark detracts too greatly..

Comment: @Matt Davison - Although they probably could use a better algorithm, i think the whole point of this is to get students to start thinking about how algorithms work and how to write an algorithm.

Comment: Bubble sort is used as a learning tool because it's the easiest sort algorithm for most people to understand.  It's a good entry point for learning about sorting and algorithms in general.  If we only taught stuff that people would actually use, the discussion of sorting would start and end with "use the library sort routine".

Comment: This question is a poster-child for how to ask a good "homework" questions. To John Fouhy's point, there is a code sample, it's well written, and the poster is trying hard to make it easy for us to help. Well done, joshhunt.

Comment: Bubble sort is *not* an easy sort algorithm for people to understand. From both my own experience and experience teaching, I can confidently say that insertion sort, selection sort, min-sort (minimum element sort), even (for some students) mergesort and quicksort are easier to understand — after all, they correspond to somewhat natural ways of sorting a list, but bubble sort is just artificial. Further, bubble sort is prone to many off-by-one errors and infinite loop errors, like this question here. As Knuth says, "the bubble sort seems to have nothing to recommend it, except a catchy name..."

Comment: I am trying to imagine the person who must exist, according to ShreevatsaR, who upon being introduced to the concept of sorting, thinks that quicksort is more straightforward to understand than bubblesort.  People learning to code would rather chew off their own feet than try to understand a recursive algorithm.

Comment: Beska, I think recursion itself is natural, and beautiful; at least to some.

Comment: @becomingGuru: To some it's "nudism", to others it's "why's the fat guy naked?  Run!"

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: If you have a hard time understanding bubble sort, then I'm not surprised that your students have a hard time understanding it as well.  That doesn't seem like a good set of data points to build an argument upon.  Knuth was talking about the *complexity* of bubble sort when he wrote the passage you quoted (pg. 110 of Vol. 3, TAoCP), not how easy or hard it is to understand.  In fact, on page 106 he says "Perhaps the most obvious way to sort by exchanges..." to introduce bubble sort.

Comment: @Bill: I understand bubble sort perfectly well (and so do most students eventually); my complaint is that it is not a natural algorithm, though the code is short. Try this experiment: give students some 40 cards and ask them to sort them. They'll start haphazardly at first, but soon they'll either: (i) pick out the smallest one each time and add it (selection sort / minsort), or (ii) put each successive card in its "proper" position (insertion sort). I've *never* seen anyone sort in several passes of swapping only adjacent elements. Maintaining an invariant inductively does not come naturally.

Comment: And some students *do* arrive at the equivalent of mergesort or quicksort. It may well be "perhaps the most obvious way to sort by exchanges", but sorting by exchanges is not natural. :-) See also "Bubble sort: an archaeological algorithmic analysis" by Owen Astrachan (http://prophet.cs.duke.edu/~ola/papers/bubble.pdf / http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/bubble/bubble.html ). There's no good reason to teach bubble sort *first*: "The bubble sort algorithm is not very useful in practice, since it runs more slowly than insertion sort and selection sort, **yet is more complicated to program.**"

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Don't you think your experiment biases the results a little?  If you hand someone 40 cards and ask them to sort them, won't they naturally sort them in a way they're accustomed to sorting *cards* (from playing card games)?  Selection sort and insertion sort are both natural ways to do this.  How do people naturally sort things when they can't physically move them around in their hands?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I wonder if the real reason bubble sort is usually taught first is so the teacher can show a progression of improving-complexity in sorting algorithms?  My algorithms professor started with bogosort http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort as an example, and each one he taught after that was an improvement over the previous one.

Comment: @Bill: Yes, I used "natural" in the sense of "well-motivated": something the students can come with by themselves (with a bit of nudging, or from analogy with sorting physical objects). I have nothing against slow/inefficient O(n^2) sorting algorithms being the first ones taught, just against the misconception that bubble sort is easiest to understand (not borne out by evidence!). For example, try asking students about the loop terminating conditions in bubble sort: it is subtler and harder to reason about than the other O(n^2) sorts, and seems to be surprisingly hard to code *correctly*.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

To explain why your script isn't working right now, I'll rename the variable `unsorted` to `sorted`.

At first, your list isn't yet sorted. Of course, we set `sorted` to `False`.

As soon as we start the `while` loop, we assume that the list is already sorted. The idea is this: as soon as we find two elements that are not in the right order, we set `sorted` back to `False`. `sorted` will remain `True` *only if there were no elements in the wrong order*.

```
sorted = False  # We haven't started sorting yet

while not sorted:
    sorted = True  # Assume the list is now sorted
    for element in range(0, length):
        if badList[element] > badList[element + 1]:
            sorted = False  # We found two elements in the wrong order
            hold = badList[element + 1]
            badList[element + 1] = badList[element]
            badList[element] = hold
    # We went through the whole list. At this point, if there were no elements
    # in the wrong order, sorted is still True. Otherwise, it's false, and the
    # while loop executes again.
```

There are also minor little issues that would help the code be more efficient or readable.

- In the `for` loop, you use the variable `element`. Technically, `element` is not an element; it's a number representing a list index. Also, it's quite long. In these cases, just use a temporary variable name, like `i` for "index".

  ```
  for i in range(0, length):
  ```
- The `range` command can also take just one argument (named `stop`). In that case, you get a list of all the integers from 0 to that argument.

  ```
  for i in range(length):
  ```
- The [Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends that variables be named in lowercase with underscores. This is a very minor nitpick for a little script like this; it's more to get you accustomed to what Python code most often resembles.

  ```
  def bubble(bad_list):
  ```
- To swap the values of two variables, write them as a tuple assignment. The right hand side gets evaluated as a tuple (say, `(badList[i+1], badList[i])` is `(3, 5)`) and then gets assigned to the two variables on the left hand side (`(badList[i], badList[i+1])`).

  ```
  bad_list[i], bad_list[i+1] = bad_list[i+1], bad_list[i]
  ```

Put it all together, and you get this:

```
my_list = [12, 5, 13, 8, 9, 65]

def bubble(bad_list):
    length = len(bad_list) - 1
    sorted = False

    while not sorted:
        sorted = True
        for i in range(length):
            if bad_list[i] > bad_list[i+1]:
                sorted = False
                bad_list[i], bad_list[i+1] = bad_list[i+1], bad_list[i]

bubble(my_list)
print my_list
```

(I removed your print statement too, by the way.)

Comment: Just on that last bit of code, bubble doesn't return anything, so the end result is that 'None' is printed. You probably either want to return the list, or do bubble(my_list) and then print my_list.

Comment: Great catch, Tung. `bubble` sorts the list in place and doesn't return anything. Therefore, sorting the list and displaying it is now performed separately.

Comment: +1 well structured, clear advice. Great to see you walk the reader through what you did and why rather than just write a quick fix.

Comment: I'm a C# programmer, so this might just be because I don't get Python, but don't you need something in the while loop to subtract 1 from length to get a normal bubble sort algorithm?

Comment: This is a naive (but not incorrect) implementation of Bubble Sort. After each iteration of the `while` loop, the largest element "bubbles up" to the end of the list. As such, after one iteration, the last element is definitely in the right place (and will not be moved by successive iterations). By subtracting 1 from length, you are optimizing the algorithm by only sorting the sublist that is not yet sorted (the `length-n` frontmost elements of the list). I elected to skip this optimization, as it is more an optimization than a vital part of the algorithm.

Comment: `Put it all together, and you get this:` ...well,you missed this one: `The range command can also take just one argument (named stop).`

Comment: Sharp eyes, MasterPeter. That was a silly oversight easily corrected, so thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: as @Wesley mentioned your code is not considering the fact that 'i' elements are bubbled at end of array(sorted) at any given point of time,so you only have to iterate over 'n-i' elements instead of n elements

Answer (score 10):

The goal of bubble sort is to move the *heavier* items at the bottom in each round, while moving the *lighter* items up. In the inner loop, where you compare the elements, **you don't have to iterate the whole list in each turn**. The *heaviest* is already placed last. The *swapped* variable is an extra check so we can mark that the list is now sorted and avoid continuing with unnecessary calculations.

```
def bubble(badList):
    length = len(badList)
    for i in range(0,length):
        swapped = False
        for element in range(0, length-i-1):
            if badList[element] > badList[element + 1]:
                hold = badList[element + 1]
                badList[element + 1] = badList[element]
                badList[element] = hold
                swapped = True
        if not swapped: break

    return badList
```

Your version 1, corrected:

```
def bubble(badList):
    length = len(badList) - 1
    unsorted = True
    while unsorted:
        unsorted = False
        for element in range(0,length):
            #unsorted = False
            if badList[element] > badList[element + 1]:
                 hold = badList[element + 1]
                 badList[element + 1] = badList[element]
                 badList[element] = hold
                 unsorted = True
                 #print badList
             #else:
                 #unsorted = True

     return badList
```

Answer (score 8):

This is what happens when you use variable name of negative meaning, you need to invert their values.  The following would be easier to understand:

```
sorted = False
while not sorted:
    ...
```

On the other hand, the logic of the algorithm is a little bit off.  You need to check whether two elements swapped during the for loop.  Here's how I would write it:

```
def bubble(values):
    length = len(values) - 1
    sorted = False
    while not sorted:
        sorted = True
        for element in range(0,length):
            if values[element] > values[element + 1]:
                 hold = values[element + 1]
                 values[element + 1] = values[element]
                 values[element] = hold
                 sorted = False
    return values
```

Comment: It's a bit too bad there's not a "WRONG" button I can hit for this answer.  I think this question and the responses - and especially the voting - need to be featured the next time Joel Spolsky talks about how well he's tuned the social interactions on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Daniel: you can do what other people with enough reputation (100) can do - downvote the wrong answer.  There's a germ of truth - negated conditions enshrined in flag variables is bad.  It isn't the whole answer, though - @McWafflestix has it right, I think.

Comment: @Jonathan - I did downvote it, but a mere downvote seems insufficient.  (It's worse than merely "not helpful")  I'll grant that the general proposition that inverted variable names confuse those reading the code, but that's not the main thrust of this answer.  The main thrust is just *wrong*.

Comment: You guys are right, I answered prematurely on this one.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @Martin - and I should point out that I'm more surprised/shocked by the voting than the answer.  The reputation system encourages you to get that first answer in, right away.  The broken part is how an incorrect answer is voted up.

Comment: I suspect that most people vote without really understanding the question in the first place (just like the way I answered the question).  OTOH, the person who asks the question has the privilege of choosing the 'right' answer afterwards.

Comment: @Martin Cote, Just edit your answer with the correct information.  Don't leave a partially incorrect answer out there.

Comment: @Martin Cote - agree with KingNestor. Either correct your answer or delete it. Why leave it there when it is acknowledged to be wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Your use of the Unsorted variable is wrong; you want to have a variable that tells you if you have swapped two elements; if you have done that, you can exit your loop, otherwise, you need to loop again.  To fix what you've got here, just put the "unsorted = false" in the body of your if case; remove your else case; and put "unsorted = true before your `for` loop.

Answer (score 6):

```
def bubble_sort(l):
    for passes_left in range(len(l)-1, 0, -1):
        for index in range(passes_left):
            if l[index] < l[index + 1]:
               l[index], l[index + 1] = l[index + 1], l[index]
    return l
```

Comment: I do beleive the question was more along the lines of 'How can this code be fixed', not 'what is your bubble sort?'

Comment: you are absolutely right, but doing it in right way is more important

Comment: True, perhaps, mtasic... but anything tagged as homework is most instructively tweaked rather than re-written (especially when it's tagged as homework by the OP).

Comment: This is a perfect re-write of the text book C bubble sort most people study. I wrote the same.

Comment: adding good information is helpful in my view. so good answer ..thought you might use flag to break earliest possible.

Answer (score 3):

#A very simple function, can be optimized (obviously) by decreasing the problem space of the 2nd array. But same O(n^2) complexity.

```
def bubble(arr):
    l = len(arr)        
    for a in range(l):
        for b in range(l-1):
            if (arr[a] < arr[b]):
            arr[a], arr[b] = arr[b], arr[a]
    return arr
```

Comment: It's a little less belabored with the way that you can swap values in Python:  `arr[a], arr[b] = arr[b], arr[a]`

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of errors in there. The first is in length, and the second is in your use of unsorted (as stated by McWafflestix). You probably also want to return the list if you're going to print it:

```
mylist = [12, 5, 13, 8, 9, 65]

def bubble(badList):
    length = len(badList) - 2
    unsorted = True

    while unsorted:
        for element in range(0,length):
            unsorted = False

            if badList[element] > badList[element + 1]:
                hold = badList[element + 1]
                badList[element + 1] = badList[element]
                badList[element] = hold
                print badList
                unsorted = True

    return badList

print bubble(mylist)
```

eta: You're right, the above is buggy as hell. My bad for not testing through some more examples.

```
def bubble2(badList):
    swapped = True
    length = len(badList) - 2

    while swapped:
        swapped = False
        for i in range(0, length):
            if badList[i] > badList[i + 1]:

                # swap
                hold = badList[i + 1]
                badList[i + 1] = badList[i]
                badList[i] = hold

                swapped = True

    return badList
```

Comment: Shouldn't the "unsorted = False" be outside the for loop?

Comment: It had a few more problems than that ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am a fresh fresh beginner, started to read about Python yesterday.
Inspired by your example I created something maybe more in the 80-ties style, but nevertheless it kinda works

```
lista1 = [12, 5, 13, 8, 9, 65]

i=0
while i < len(lista1)-1:
    if lista1[i] > lista1[i+1]:
        x = lista1[i]
        lista1[i] = lista1[i+1]
        lista1[i+1] = x
        i=0
        continue
    else:
        i+=1

print(lista1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the original algorithm is that if you had a lower number further in the list, it would not bring it to the correct sorted position.  The program needs to go back the the beginning each time to ensure that the numbers sort all the way through.

I simplified the code and it will now work for any list of numbers regardless of the list and even if there are repeating numbers.  Here's the code

```
mylist = [9, 8, 5, 4, 12, 1, 7, 5, 2]
print mylist

def bubble(badList):
    length = len(badList) - 1
    element = 0
    while element < length:
        if badList[element] > badList[element + 1]:
            hold = badList[element + 1]
            badList[element + 1] = badList[element]
            badList[element] = hold
            element = 0
            print badList
        else:
            element = element + 1

print bubble(mylist)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def bubble_sort(l):
    exchanged = True
    iteration = 0
    n = len(l)

    while(exchanged):
        iteration += 1
        exchanged = False

        # Move the largest element to the end of the list
        for i in range(n-1):
            if l[i] > l[i+1]:
                exchanged = True
                l[i], l[i+1] = l[i+1], l[i]
        n -= 1   # Largest element already towards the end

    print 'Iterations: %s' %(iteration)
    return l
```

Comment: Bubble larger element all the way to the end. And decrement the end counter, "n" so that you will not have to compare it again. Continue with the while loop as long as there are exchanges.

Worst Case: O(N^2)
Best Case: O(N)

Answer (score 1):

```
def bubbleSort(alist):
if len(alist) <= 1:
    return alist
for i in range(0,len(alist)):
   print "i is :%d",i
   for j in range(0,i):
      print "j is:%d",j
      print "alist[i] is :%d, alist[j] is :%d"%(alist[i],alist[j])
      if alist[i] > alist[j]:
         alist[i],alist[j] = alist[j],alist[i]
return alist
```

alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20,-23,-34,16,11,11,11]

print bubbleSort(alist)

Comment: Please indent your code sample correctly: this is, of course, especially important in Python. You might also want to explain why your solution is worth considering considering there is also an answer with 100 votes

Answer (score 1):

```
def bubble_sort(a):
    t = 0
    sorted = False # sorted = False because we have not began to sort
    while not sorted:
    sorted = True # Assume sorted = True first, it will switch only there is any change
        for key in range(1,len(a)):
            if a[key-1] > a[key]:
                sorted = False
                t = a[key-1]; a[key-1] = a[key]; a[key] = t;
    print a
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler example:

```
a = len(alist)-1
while a > 0:
    for b in range(0,a):
        #compare with the adjacent element
        if alist[b]>=alist[b+1]:
            #swap both elements
            alist[b], alist[b+1] = alist[b+1], alist[b]
    a-=1
```

This simply takes the elements from 0 to a(basically, all the unsorted elements in that round) and compares it with its adjacent element, and making a swap if it is greater than its adjacent element. At the end the round, the last element is sorted, and the process runs again without it, until all elements have been sorted.

There is no need for a condition whether `sort` is true or not.

Note that this algorithm takes into consideration the position of the numbers only when swapping, so repeated numbers will not affect it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def bubble_sort(li):
    l = len(li)
    tmp = None
    sorted_l = sorted(li)
    while (li != sorted_l):
        for ele in range(0,l-1):
            if li[ele] > li[ele+1]:
                tmp = li[ele+1]
                li[ele+1] = li [ele]
                li[ele] = tmp
    return li
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def bubbleSort ( arr ):
    swapped = True 
    length = len ( arr )
    j = 0

    while swapped:
        swapped = False
        j += 1 
        for i in range ( length  - j ):
            if arr [ i ] > arr [ i + 1 ]:
                # swap
                tmp = arr [ i ]
                arr [ i ] = arr [ i + 1]
                arr [ i + 1 ] = tmp 

                swapped = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # test list
    a = [ 67, 45, 39, -1, -5, -44 ];

    print ( a )
    bubbleSort ( a )
    print ( a )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def bubblesort(array):
    for i in range(len(array)-1):
        for j in range(len(array)-1-i):
            if array[j] > array[j+1]:
                array[j], array[j+1] = array[j+1], array[j]
    return(array)

print(bubblesort([3,1,6,2,5,4]))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [5,4,3,1,6,8,10,9] # array not sorted

for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(i, len(arr)):
        if(arr[i] > arr[j]):
            arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]

            print (arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

**I consider adding my solution because ever solution here is having**

1. *greater time*
2. *greater space complexity*
3. *or doing too much operations*

**then is should be**

***So, here is  my solution:***

---

```
def countInversions(arr):
    count = 0
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n):
        _count = count
        for j in range(0, n - i - 1):
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]:
                count += 1
                arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]
        if _count == count:
            break
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in a shorter implementation using a list comprehension:

```
def bubble_sort(lst: list) -> None:
    [swap_items(lst, i, i+1) for left in range(len(lst)-1, 0, -1) for i in range(left) if lst[i] > lst[i+1]]


def swap_items(lst: list, pos1: int, pos2: int) -> None:
    lst[pos1], lst[pos2] = lst[pos2], lst[pos1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different variation of bubble sort without `for` loop. Basically you are considering the `lastIndex` of the `array` and slowly `decrementing` it until it first index of the array.

The `algorithm` will continue to move through the array like this until an entire pass is made without any `swaps` occurring.

The bubble is sort is basically `Quadratic Time: O(n²)` when it comes to performance.

```
class BubbleSort: 
  def __init__(self, arr):
    self.arr = arr;

  def bubbleSort(self):
    count = 0;
    lastIndex = len(self.arr) - 1;
    
    while(count < lastIndex):
      if(self.arr[count] > self.arr[count + 1]):
        self.swap(count)  
      count = count + 1;

      if(count == lastIndex):
        count = 0;
        lastIndex = lastIndex - 1;   

  def swap(self, count):
    temp = self.arr[count];
    self.arr[count] = self.arr[count + 1];
    self.arr[count + 1] = temp;
    
arr = [9, 1, 5, 3, 8, 2]
p1 = BubbleSort(arr)

print(p1.bubbleSort())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def bubblesort(L,s):
    if s >-1 :
        bubblesort(L,s-1)
        for i in range(len(L)-1-s):
            if L[i]>L[i+1]:
                temp = L[i+1]
                L[i+1] = L[i]
                L[i] = temp

    return L

Nlist = [3,50,7,1,8,11,9,0,-1,5]
print(bubblesort(Nlist,len(Nlist)))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Answers provided by the-fury and Martin Cote fixed the problem of the infinite loop, but my code would still not work correctly (for a larger list, it would not sort correctly.). I ended up ditching the `unsorted` variable and used a counter instead.

```
def bubble(badList):
    length = len(badList) - 1
    n = 0
    while n < len(badList):
        for element in range(0,length):
            if badList[element] > badList[element + 1]:
                hold = badList[element + 1]
                badList[element + 1] = badList[element]
                badList[element] = hold
                n = 0
            else:
                n += 1
    return badList

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mylist = [90, 10, 2, 76, 17, 66, 57, 23, 57, 99]
    print bubble(mylist)
```

If anyone could provide any pointers on how to improve my code in the comments, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can speed up a bubble-sort by skipping the portion of your list that you know is already sorted (because of previous iterations). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Alternative_implementations

Comment: again, all you really need to do is use a boolean (call it untouched).  declare it outside your loop; loop until untouched = true.  within your while loop, set untouched to be true; in the body of your if, set untouched to be false.  Doing this, you can ditch your else case.  in this way, if you ever switch two elements, your loop will continue; if you don't, the loop will not.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
a = int(input("Enter Limit"))


val = []

for z in range(0,a):
    b = int(input("Enter Number in List"))
    val.append(b)


for y in range(0,len(val)):
   for x in range(0,len(val)-1):
       if val[x]>val[x+1]:
           t = val[x]
           val[x] = val[x+1]
           val[x+1] = t

print(val)
```

Answer (score -1):

idk if this might help you after 9 years...
its a simple bubble sort program

```
    l=[1,6,3,7,5,9,8,2,4,10]

    for i in range(1,len(l)):
        for j in range (i+1,len(l)):
            if l[i]>l[j]:
                l[i],l[j]=l[j],l[i]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def merge_bubble(arr):
    k = len(arr)
    while k>2:
        for i in range(0,k-1):
            for j in range(0,k-1):
                if arr[j] > arr[j+1]:
                    arr[j],arr[j+1] = arr[j+1],arr[j]

        return arr
        break
    else:
        if arr[0] > arr[1]:
            arr[0],arr[1] = arr[1],arr[0]
        return arr
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def bubble_sort(l):
    for i in range(len(l) -1):
        for j in range(len(l)-i-1):
            if l[j] > l[j+1]:
                l[j],l[j+1] = l[j+1], l[j]
    return l
```

Comment: It would be better to add some explanation to your code.

Answer (score -1):

```
def bubble_sorted(arr:list):
    while True:
        for i in range(0,len(arr)-1):
            count = 0
            if arr[i] > arr[i+1]:
                count += 1
                arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
        if count == 0:
            break
    return arr
arr = [30,20,80,40,50,10,60,70,90]
print(bubble_sorted(arr))
#[20, 30, 40, 50, 10, 60, 70, 80, 90]
```

Answer (score -3):

`def bubbleSort(a):
    def swap(x, y):
        temp = a[x]
        a[x] = a[y]
        a[y] = temp
    #outer loop
    for j in range(len(a)): 
        #slicing to the center, inner loop, python style
        for i in range(j, len(a) - j):

            #find the min index and swap
            if a[i] < a[j]:
                swap(j, i)
            #find the max index and swap
            if a[i] > a[len(a) - j - 1]:
                swap(len(a) - j - 1, i)
    return a`