# How to print a string multiple times?

Tags: python

How can I repeat a string multiple times, multiple times? I know I can use a for loop, but I would like to repeat a string `x` times per row, over `n` rows.

For example, if the user enters `2`, the output would be:

```
@@
@@
@@
@@
```

Where `x` equals 2, and `n` equals 4.

Comment: use another for loop ? your question isn't very clear...

Comment: If you know how to do a for, then you know how to print something multiple times <_<

Comment: Have you attempted at all to do this?

Comment: See my perfect homework question ^_^ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895371/bubble-sort-homework

Comment: @joshhunt: Reopening upon request.  Your offer to edit is accepted.  Moderator flags are legally binding agreements!  ;)  Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
for i in range(3):
    print "Your text here"
```

Or

```
for i in range(3):
    print("Your text here")
```

Comment: your interpretation was better than mine I think ;-)

Answer (score 46):

If you want to print `something = '@'` 2 times in a line, you can write this:

```
print(something * 2)
```

If you want to print 4 lines of something, you can use a for loop:

```
for i in range(4):
     print(something)
```

Comment: How would I do this with a number? print 5*10 would just put 50. I cant use the str() operator.

Comment: @marsh `print "5"*10`

Comment: How do we print the same with spaces in between and not at the end??
Eg : the output has to be "something something"

Answer (score 4):

It amazes me that this simple answer did not occur in the previous answers.

In my viewpoint, the easiest way to print a string on multiple lines, is the following :

`print("Random String \n" * 100)`, where 100 stands for the number of lines to be printed.

Answer (score 3):

So I take it if the user enters `2`, you want the output to be something like:

```
!!
!!
!!
!!
```

Correct?

To get that, you would need something like:

```
rows = 4
times_to_repeat = int(raw_input("How many times to repeat per row? ")

for i in range(rows):
    print "!" * times_to_repeat
```

That would result in:

```
How many times to repeat per row?
>> 4
!!!!
!!!!
!!!!
!!!!
```

I have not tested this, but it should run error free.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Old answer erased in response to updated question.

You just store the string in a variable:

```
separator = "!" * int(raw_input("Enter number: "))
print separator
do_stuff()
print separator
other_stuff()
print separator
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rows = int(input('How many stars in each row do you want?'))
columns = int(input('How many columns do you want?'))
i = 0

for i in range(columns): 
    print ("*" * rows)

i = i + 1
```

Comment: Is this tested? Some description would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear can't you just repeat the for loop?

```
a=[1,2,3]

for i in a:
    print i
1
2
3


for i in a:
    print i
1
2
3
```

Comment: Sorry about that, the input is from the keyboard denoting a number, with a forloop "!" is printed input number of times in row. Now i want that output to be printed 3 more times on seperate lines, hopes that clears any ambiguity.

Comment: @user718531 ok, others have provided you with an answer so I'll delete my post

Answer (score 0):

```
def repeat_char_rows_cols(char, rows, cols):
    return (char*cols + '\n')*rows

>>> print(repeat_char_rows_cols('@', 4, 2))
@@
@@
@@
@@
```

Answer (score 0):

For example if you want to repeat a word called "HELP" for 1000 times the following is the best way.

```
word = ['HELP']
repeat = 1000 * word
```

Then you will get the list of 1000 words and make that into a data frame if you want by using following command

```
word_data =pd.DataFrame(repeat)
word_data.columns = ['list_of_words'] #To change the column name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n=int(input())
w=input()
print(f'{w}\n'*n)
# this will print the word(w) , n times in separte lines
```