# Python - Print a string a certain number of times

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python, Printing multiple times,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293421/python-printing-multiple-times)

I'd like to know how to print a string such as "String" 500 hundred times?

Comment: Write a loop with a print statement.

Comment: How you want to print it? On the new line each? separated by spaces? Or just one by one?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use repetition (`*`):

```
print('String' * 500)
```

In this way Python will first create the whole string (`"StringStr...String"`) in memory and only then will print it.

If you don't want to use so much memory, then you can use a for loop:

```
for i in range(500):
    print('String', end='')
print()
```

`end=''` is needed to prevent Python from printing end-of-line characters after each `print`. `print()` at the end is needed to print the end-of-line character after the last `print`.