# How to print a string x times based on user input

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple application that will print a word a specific number of times. I have this code:

```
# Double Words
times = input('How many times would you like to repeat your word?')
word = input('Enter your word:')
for times in times:
    print(word)
```

When I run the code, `word` is only printed once, despite the loop. What is wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Use the range function, `for i in range(int(times))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a string multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293421/how-to-print-a-string-multiple-times)

Answer (score 0):

```
times = int(input('How many times would you like to repeat your word?'))

word = input('Enter your word:')

for i in range(times):
    print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because you use same variable to iterate over the times and better use range():

```
# Double Words

times = input('Ho w many times would you like to repeat your word?')

word = input('Enter your word:')

for time in range(int(times)):
    print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
for n in range(int(times)):

   print(word)
```

But this may give you error as if the user enters a non-integer value.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do it in one line is the following, no looping required:

```py
times = input('Ho w many times would you like to repeat your word?')
word = input('Enter your word:')

print('\n'.join([word] * int(times)))
```

`'\n'.join()` to add a newline between each element.

`[word] * int(times)` makes a `times` long list - with each element being `word` so that you can use `join()` on it.

*Note: If you don't care about the newline between entries, you can just do `print(word * int(times))`.*