# How to call a function multiple times in Python?

Tags: python, repeat

How do I loop this python script? For example I want 100 of the GGIXX-XXXXXXX

```
import random

def random_gen():
    return f".type('GGI{random.randint(1, 50)}-{random.randint(1000000, 9999999)}')"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a string multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293421/how-to-print-a-string-multiple-times)

Comment: You need a loop. You might want to read about the [`for`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) statement in the tutorial.

Comment: Yea but like everytime I try it breaks so if someone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
import random


def random_gen():
    return f".type('GGI{random.randint(1, 50)}-{random.randint(1000000, 9999999)}')"


for _ in range(100):
    print(random_gen())
```

Out:

```
.type('GGI45-5220704')
.type('GGI37-3996932')
.type('GGI2-6482051')
.type('GGI36-2371399')
.type('GGI9-6880645')
.type('GGI12-1733716')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` statement or a `while` statement.

A `for` loop is used for iterating over a sequence. With the `while` loop we can execute a set of statements as long as a condition is true.

**For Loop**

```
import random

def random_gen():
    return f".type('GGI{random.randint(1, 50)}-{random.randint(1000000, 9999999)}')"

for i in range(100):
    print("{:03}: {}".format(i, random_gen()))
```

**While Loop**

```
import random

def random_gen():
    return f".type('GGI{random.randint(1, 50)}-{random.randint(1000000, 9999999)}')"

i = 0    
while i < 100:
    print("{:03}: {}".format(i, random_gen()))
    i += 1
```

The output will be the same:

```
000: .type('GGI50-2461961')
001: .type('GGI14-3540227')
002: .type('GGI42-2802782')
003: .type('GGI50-9538359')
004: .type('GGI13-2128867')
005: .type('GGI22-8774426')
006: .type('GGI24-6997243')
007: .type('GGI38-4704988')
008: .type('GGI38-7738663')
009: .type('GGI8-5558144')
010: .type('GGI13-5474296')
...
090: .type('GGI3-4898938')
091: .type('GGI36-4209837')
092: .type('GGI18-6721739')
093: .type('GGI49-8878156')
094: .type('GGI16-2819595')
095: .type('GGI16-1172404')
096: .type('GGI24-2772872')
097: .type('GGI35-9967247')
098: .type('GGI25-8327445')
099: .type('GGI9-4671711')
```

Here you can find more info:[Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while)