# Bubble Sort Algorithm in Python - Last Number Not Sorting

Tags: python, algorithm

The algorithm sorts all the numbers except the first one, and sets it as last. Please help!

```
def bubbleSort(numbers): # Bubble Sort Algorithm
    numbers = list(numbers)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        for j in range(len(numbers) - i):
            if numbers[j] < numbers[j-1]: 
                       temp = numbers[j-1]
                       numbers[j-1] = numbers[j]
                       numbers[j] = temp

    print numbers
    print numbers
```

Comment: Quick note: You don't need to set `i = 0` and `j = 0` explicitly. that happens as part of the `for` loop, which says "let `i` assume the values in `range(n)` - `0,1,2,3,4...n`.

Comment: also note that swapping two numbers can be better expressed as `a, b = b, a`, as in `numbers[j-1], numbers[j] = numbers[j], numbers[j-1]`. See http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html (required reading for all python programmers.)

Comment: Finally, note `numbers = list(numbers)` may have strange effects when you pass in arguments that aren't a list. For example: `list("foobar") ` gives `['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']`, `list( {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'} )` gives `['key2', 'key1']`. If you want to ensure that your function is getting a list, it's better to test the condition `type (numbers) is list`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that sometimes [j-1] becomes negative. In python, numbers[-1] means "get the last element in numbers". Here is a fixed version:

```
def bubbleSort(numbers): # Bubble Sort Algorithm
    nums = list(numbers)
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(nums)):
            if numbers[j] < numbers[i]:
                numbers[j], numbers[i] = numbers[i], numbers[j]

    print numbers
```

You'll notice that it is also possible to swap numbers without a temp variable in python as well

Comment: Ah, beat me to it. To be more precise, when `j = 0` then you're comparing the first and last elements of the list.

To clarify the meaning of `numbers[-1]`, try `foo = [1, 2, 3, 4]; foo[-1]; foo[-2]; foo[0:-1]`.

Comment: is it selection sort instead of bubble sort?

Comment: @Bear, this is a slightly "optimized" bubble sort where we move along once there is no possibility of swaps any more. It still has O(n^2) time complexity however.

Comment: No: selection sort looks for the biggest number in the unsorted part of the list, then moves it to the top of the list. Bubble sort works through the list doing swaps between adjacent values in the list.

Comment: @habitue: "optimised bubble sort" cracks me up every time. Though for the best bubble sort possible in Python, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895371/bubble-sort-homework

Comment: I mostly changed it because I think this is a bit cleaner since we aren't doing subtraction etc in the indices

Comment: In habitue solution ,it finds smallest in each round and move it to the left... So why it is not selection sort? Selection sort also is O(N^2)

Comment: It doesn't look for the smallest number directly and then move it to the front of the list. It does a dumb pairwise comparison like in bubblesort, the only difference being that we stop comparing to places in the list that are already sorted (which is somewhat like selection sort).

Answer (score 0):

I would not describe this as a 'Bubble sort' as it does not swap the list elements that are next to each other.  Its more like a 'Selection sort' as it is looking through the list and comparing each element with the first then swapping the smallest number with the first.

It seems to be a bubble/selection mash-up.