# Simple Sort, file handling

Tags: python, sorting, file-io

So I have a few lines of code that put a users name and score into a file:

```
hs = open("hst.txt", "a")
hs.write(name + " ")
hs.write(str(score) + "\n")
hs.close()
```

Without using a function already in python can someone show me how to perform a sort (preferably a simple sort) on this to put it in order from largest numbered score to smallest?

Comment: If you're doing this for some assignment, here's a good post to learn from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895371/bubble-sort-homework

Comment: A bubble sort could work but a simple sort would be preferable, do you know where I could find information on that?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with simple sorts, just types of sorts that could be classified as simple? Maybe look at insertion sorts implemented in Python? :)

Comment: In order to do that, you will first have to read all the scores in the file, sort them and then write them out.