# How to use linear search to arrange nested lists?

Tags: python, python-2.7, insertion-sort

Currently working with a text file that is read into python and then must be made into lists with a list (nested I guess?) So far I've tried using linear searching code but it only checks one of the lists in the nested list:

```
def populationreader():
    with open("PopulationofAnnecy", "r") as in_file:
        nested = [line.strip().split(',') for line in in_file][1:]
        print nested
```

This yields the following nested list:

```
[['Alabama', '126', '79', '17'], ['Alaska', '21', '100', '10'], ['Arizona', '190', '59', '16'], ['Arkansas', '172', '49', '28'], ['California', '4964', '76', '22'] etc …. ]
```

But it should look something more like:

```
[[California 4964,76,22],[Texas 3979,62,23],[New York 1858,69,20],[Virginia 1655,60,19]etc …. ]
```

I've tried using something along the lines of this (pseudo):

```
for index in range(1,len(alist)):

     currentvalue = alist[index]
     position = index

     while position>0 and alist[position-1]>currentvalue:
         alist[position]=alist[position-1]
         position = position-1

     alist[position]=currentvalue
```

Trying to do it without using the built in python sort() or sorted() functions but I'm just having trouble sorting things within a list

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your list read in from the file, you can use `sort` or `sorted`, but you want to make sure you sort by the second element `[1]` and make sure to `reverse` also. Otherwise the default is to sort by the first element of the list (the state name) and alphabetically since it is a `string`.

```
l = [['Alabama', '126', '79', '17'],
     ['Alaska', '21', '100', '10'],
     ['Arizona', '190', '59', '16'],
     ['Arkansas', '172', '49', '28'],
     ['California', '4964', '76', '22'],
     ['Texas', '3979','62','23'],
     ['New York', '1858','69','20'],
     ['Virginia', '1655','60','19']]

sorted(l, key = lambda i: int(i[1]), reverse=True)
```

Output

```
[['California', '4964', '76', '22'],
 ['Texas', '3979', '62', '23'], 
 ['New York', '1858', '69', '20'], 
 ['Virginia', '1655', '60', '19'], 
 ['Arizona', '190', '59', '16'], 
 ['Arkansas', '172', '49', '28'], 
 ['Alabama', '126', '79', '17'], 
 ['Alaska', '21', '100', '10']]
```

Comment: that would be great but I'm trying to avoid using the sort() or sorted() functions. Is there any way to use linear or even bubble search in a case like this?

Comment: Yes you can write your own sorting algorithm. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895371/bubble-sort-homework) for bubble sorting. Basically for your case, just do that but make sure to sort by the second element of the list, and covert it to `int`.